# How do I compute a compile-time value using the size of members of unions?

Tags: c++

Consider the following data structure:

```
union LambdaBox {                                                           
    struct {                                                                
        uint64_t full;                                                      
        char lambda[];                                                      
    } data;                                                                 
    char padding[64];                                          
};
```

The size of the member variable `full` is clearly known at compile time.

**How can I refer to it directly without first creating an object of type `LambdaBox`?**

More specifically, I am trying to write an expression (evaluated at compile-time) that is semantically equivalent to the third statement below.

```
int main(){
    // This works
    printf("The total size allowed is %zu\n", 56L);
    // This also works
    printf("The total size of LambdaBox is %zu\n", sizeof(LambdaBox));

    // What is the correct syntax for the semantic meaning of the following line?
    printf("The total size allowed is %zu\n", sizeof(LambdaBox) -
            sizeof(LambdaBox::data::full);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `decltype` (C++11 and later):

   ```
   sizeof(LambdaBox) - sizeof decltype(LambdaBox::data)::full
   ```

   On coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b566a890b4143838
2. You can avoid the need for `decltype` by naming the anonymous type of `data`.
3. You can use the fact that the `sizeof`-operand is always [*unevaluated*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions) to avoid temporaries even if you cannot use `decltype` (Works even on ancient compilers):

   ```
   sizeof(LambdaBox) - sizeof LambdaBox().data.full
   ```

   On coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14bcbd6995c9dd8c
4. The direct way:

   ```
   sizeof(LambdaBox) - sizeof LambdaBox::data.full
   ```

   On coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f984d8e9462ca2c2

Be aware that flexible array-members are a C99 feature not even in C++14 though (GCC and clang accept it as an extension).

Comment: I'm confused by your last comment. Are you saying this solution will *not* work with C++?

Comment: I'm saying that an array-member without length is not core C++, but C99. It is accepted as an extension by many implementations though, so you can use it.

Comment: 1 for correctness, but unfortunately due to an ancient compiler I cannot actually use it in my system.

Comment: @merlin: Added second option.

Comment: I did not realize that `sizeof` was unevaluated. I hope you don't mind the edit to add the link for that.

Comment: I'm fine with any polishing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one workaround I found which does not use C++11 features, which my compiler `g++ 4.4.7` does not fully support.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>


union LambdaBox {                                                           
    struct {                                                                
        uint64_t full;                                                      
        char lambda[];                                                      
    } data;                                                                 
    char padding[64];                                          

    static uint64_t getMaxSize() { 
        return sizeof(LambdaBox) - sizeof(data.full);  
    }                              

};                                                                          

int main(){
    printf("The total size allowed is %zu\n", 56L);
    printf("The total size of LambdaBox is %zu\n", sizeof(LambdaBox));

    printf("The total size allowed is %zu\n", LambdaBox::getMaxSize());

}
```

Comment: Be aware that yours is not a compile-time-constant, unless you add `constexpr` (C++11). If you do, you can use `decltype` just fine anyway.